# Third party sdk dll works with WPF but not UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a third party sdk provided as .dll and tlb. It works fine with WPF, but when I add it to UWP project, once I reach the screen that uses the sdk it throws

> instance of the COM component with CLSID
>   {DBA84AA0-3342-4AF0-96ED-3D8D08D544F3} using CoCreateInstanceFromApp
>   failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). Please
>   make sure your COM object is in the allowed list of
>   CoCreateInstanceFromApp

Is there anyway to make the .dll or tbl, work with the UWP app I am developing. I have both x64 and x86 versions of the .dll.

Comment: guessing its not supported in UWP

Comment: Might want to give this a read (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fceb5d50-36fd-474c-b01f-72cd26ba64b8/uwpinterop-exception?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: Another alternative solution is to include the library into a headless wpf app and use Desktop Bridge to call the method.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the third party SDK that you're using doesn't support UWP. WPF and UWP use very different APIs.

You will have to request them to update their libraries and distribute those to you.

Comment: The fact that the SDK is calling CoCreateInstanceFromApp instead of CoCreateInstance means it should be supporting UWP.

Comment: `CoCreateInstanceFromApp` is supported for UWP, but it only allows creation of a specific set of CLSIDs. The one the SDK is trying to create is presumably not on that list.